# authentication firebase (error en los métodos) android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, método

Necesito de su ayuda, estoy haciendo un aplicación donde estoy usando el authentication de Firebase. Este ya te da un asistente, te ayuda en casi todo pero  hay un  método que no entiendo y que me genera un error.

```
"Cannot resolve method UpdateUI(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser)"
```

ejemplo del código:

```
    public void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
       FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
       updateUI(currentUser);
    }
```

Si debo crear no se ¿como? o ¿que hace? ya el asistente te lo genera así.

Answer (score 1):

updateUI es del quickstart de Auth, este es el metodo si lo queres implementar

```
 private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null) {
            mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.google_status_fmt, user.getEmail()));
            mDetailTextView.setText(getString(R.string.firebase_status_fmt, user.getUid()));

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mStatusTextView.setText(R.string.signed_out);
            mDetailTextView.setText(null);

            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

si queres usarlo sin, aca te dejo el codigo para crear y loguear un usuario sin updateUI

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                          //Logica luego de loguearse

                        } else {

                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
```

Lo mismo para crear un usuario, cambiamos `signInWithEmailAndPassword` por `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Answer (score 0):

Bueno creo que contestarse uno mismo su pregunta es algo raro, encontre un ejemplo que también te da el asistente de Firebase [github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android).
espero a alguien le sirva igual que a mi.

Comment: por favor añade lo relevante de la respuesta que pones pero aquí, ya que las respuestas que son solo enlaces se consideran de baja calidad por que si la página deja de estar entonces nadie mas podrá consultarlo